# I am getting this error when I run the below java code

Tags: java

I'm getting this error when I run the below java code

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      at my.time.main(time.java:9)

```
package my;
package com.mkyong.date;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class time {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
        String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";

        //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;

        try {
            d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
            d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

            //in milliseconds
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
            System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
            System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
            System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the package `my` and import the class `date`:

```
package my;
import com.mkyong.date;
```

Comment: again i am getting error                                                                   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at my.time.main(time.java:8)

Comment: @sisirreddy 
which line is 9

Comment: there no need of `import` means second statement is not needed. @sisirreddy

Comment: Since you don't have a class called `date`. try to use either first or second statement fromyour code. @sisirreddy

Comment: The OP have updated the question because before had error with package and import date @Satya

Comment: No. OP not updated the code.. OP just copied this code from some -- site and trying to creating OP own package by adding first package statement. thats the error. @Abdelhak

Answer (score 2):

You set `package`two times:

```
package my;
package com.mkyong.date;
```

It is only allowed one time. You should set your package to match your classes path.